# looping through a list of vectors in r

Tags: r, vector

i am trying to loop through a list a vectors and assign values on the way:
I generate 10 vectors like this:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  vecname <- paste('blub',i,sep='')
  assign(vecname,vector(mode='numeric',length = my_len))
} 

ls() = blub1, blub2 .... blub10
```

now i have another vector `bla <- 100:109`

what i basically want to do is

```
blub1[1] <- bla[1]
blub2[1] <- bla[2]
blub3[1] <- bla[3]
...
blub10[1] <- bla[10]
```

I am pretty sure there is an more elegant solution to his problem.
Help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: The "R way" is not to have 10 separate vectors in your workspace, but a single list of those 10 vectors

Comment: `lapply(bla, '[') %>% setNames(sprintf("blub%02d", 1:10))` will give you a list of 10 object, each containing a value of `bla`. Note that you would `require(dplyr)` to do the `%>%` pipe.

Comment: Or simply `setNames(as.list(bla), paste0('blub', bla))`.

Comment: @AdamQuek You don't need `dplyr` but `magrittr` to work with pipes.

Comment: Rule 236: `fortunes::fortune(236)`

*The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you should never use the assign function.*
   -- Greg Snow
      R-help (July 2009)

Comment: Thanks for the answers that works well of course,

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I would do it, following the "R way" of "lists, not for loops":

```
my_len <- 3
blub <- replicate(10, vector(mode = "numeric", length = my_len), simplify = FALSE)
bla <- 100:109
blub <- Map(function(a, b) {
  a[1] <- b
  a
}, blub, bla)
# [[1]]
# [1] 100   0   0
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 101   0   0
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 102   0   0
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 103   0   0
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 104   0   0
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 105   0   0
# 
# [[7]]
# [1] 106   0   0
# 
# [[8]]
# [1] 107   0   0
# 
# [[9]]
# [1] 108   0   0
# 
# [[10]]
# [1] 109   0   0
```